# Using FetchContent results in LNK1104: can not open "onetbb.lib"

Tags: c++, cmake, linker, lib, fetchcontent

I have the following CMakeLists.txt file to add third party libraries based on CLion:

```
# onetbb
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
        onetbb
        GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB.git
        GIT_TAG master
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(
        onetbb
)
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        ${onetbb_SOURCE_DIR}/include
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
        onetbb
)
```

I can write the code without any error,
but When I try to build project, I got the following error:

> error LNK1104: cannot open file 'onetbb.lib'

I want to know how to solve this problem, someone can give a better way to add third party libraries is better.

Comment: Calling `FetchContent_MakeAvailable` is effectively `add_subdirectory` call, which tells CMake to descend into the directory with the referenced project. You need to know which **targets** are created in that project, and choose the target which represents needed library. E.g. the script [src/tbb/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/blob/master/src/tbb/CMakeLists.txt) (which is part of oneTBB project) creates the target named `tbb`. You may link your executable with that target by using `target_link_libraries` command.